# How to standardize convertnumber usage in JSF for various components?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In my project I use lots of h:outputtext with f:convertnumber to apply a pattern to my numeric data.

```
<h:outputText  value="#{stock.price}">
    <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="" groupingUsed="true" maxFractionDigits="2" type="currency" />
</h:outputText>
```

Copying and pasting this pattern when needed for other data seems to be easy. But it is also unmanageable; when used more, changing the pattern seems to require lots of search/replace operations.

How can I make this pattern be reusable and managed in a central location.

Comment: make a custom tag I guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest is to create a custom converter which extends the desired standard converter and wherein you set the desired defaults in the constructor.

```
@FacesConverter("defaultNumberConverter")
public class DefaultNumberConverter extends NumberConverter {

    public DefaultNumberConverter() {
        setCurrencySymbol("");
        setGroupingUsed(true);
        setMaxFractionDigits(2);
        setType("currency");
    }

}
```

Use it as follows:

```html
<h:outputText value="#{stock.price}" converter="defaultNumberConverter" />
```