# @FacesConverter forClass-Attribute does not work

Tags: jsf, converters

I wanted just test out the `@FacesConverter`-functionality and get stucked on the `forClass`-atrribute - it does not work - here is my Example:

The Converter Class:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Double.class)
public class TextToDoubleConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Double getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) throws ConverterException {
        Double doubledValue = null;
        try {
            doubledValue = new Double(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Fehler: ...");
            facesMessage.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ConverterException(facesMessage);
        }

        return doubledValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

}
```

ManagedBean:

```
@Model
public class SomeBean {


    private Double someCommvertDouble;


    public Double getSomeCommvertDouble() {
        return someCommvertDouble;
    }

    public void setSomeCommvertDouble(Double someCommvertDouble) {
        this.someCommvertDouble = someCommvertDouble;
    }
}
```

index.xhtml:

```
    <h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{someBean.someCommvertDouble}">
<!--        <f:converter converterId="com.java.ee.jsf.TextToIntConverter"/>  -->    
 </h:inputText>

    </h:form>
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: You don't really need the `forClass` property to use the converter, just write `@FacesConverter("TextToIntConverter")` and call it in the input `h:inputText value="#{someBean.someCommvertDouble}" converter="TextToIntConverter" />`

Comment: I know...i just wondering why it is not working with the `forClass` method....

Comment: Are you sure `someBean.someCommvertDouble` is a `double` ? because if it's not, then it will not work

Comment: no it is not `double` but `Double`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@FacesConverter(forClass)` works only on custom types for which not already a [built-in converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/package-summary.html) exist. The `Double` type already has a builtin converter, the [`DoubleConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/DoubleConverter.html). Any converter already defined in a `faces-config.xml` such as the builtin one will always have higher precedence over those annotated with `@FacesConverter`.

Your converter will only work if you explicitly register it in webapp's `faces-config.xml` as below instead of being annotated.

```
<converter>
    <converter-for-class>java.lang.Double</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>com.example.YourDoubleConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

By the way, consider extending from `DoubleConverter` or `NumberConverter` and delegating to it. You can find some concrete examples in below links to closely related questions.

#### See also:

- [validating decimals inputs in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498617/validating-decimals-inputs-in-jsf/)
- [Need <f:convertNumber> to throw error when fractions or separator characters are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848675/need-fconvertnumber-to-throw-error-when-fractions-or-separator-characters-are/)
- [convertNumber shows 0,00 as a negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947570/convertnumber-shows-0-00-as-a-negative-value/)
- [How to standardize convertnumber usage in JSF for various components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772127/how-to-standardize-convertnumber-usage-in-jsf-for-various-components/)